# java maven - override version of another dependency

Tags: java, scala, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

I have two dependencies that I cannot change due to the requirements. Both are using scala dependency in maven.

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

One dependency is a jar file library added to the project while the other dependency is a maven dependency.

The problem is that both require the scala dependency, one with version 2.8.2 and one with version 2.10.2. Both do not function with the other version number.

The bottom line is: how can I set the maven dependency to use 2.10.2 while the jar file 2.8.2?

Comment: are you trying to build play 2 framework webapps with maven?

Comment: No, I'm not trying to achieve that. Both dependencies I need are just some basic libraries, but I need both of them and I can't change their code. They both require the scala-library but use a different version number. The question is how do I do that.

Comment: I do not think that is possible if both libraries are compile dependencies, without porting the older from scala 2.8 to scala 2.10; that's because of scala not being binary compatible. I am not a scala expert tough, hope you will find better answers and in the meanwhile you get my +1

Answer (score 1):

One crazy way to solve this problem would be to create two separate maven artifacts, one of which references the other:

```
Scala version 1        Scala Version 2
      |                    |
     \ /                  \ /
  Art1fact 1 --------> Artifact 2
```

Now, In Artifact 1, use the [Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to create a jar-with-dependencies (see [Maven-Assembly-Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) for details) [using class relocation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) (e.g. Mapping all classes from scala.* to old.scala.*). The important part is that Artifact 2 would only reference the shaded version of Artifact 1, hence ommitting the Scala dependency.

([ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) will let you achieve similar results)

Comment: That sounds like a whole lot of work and would require me to constantly modify the jars right? As the library is changing from time to time this seems like a lot of work?

Comment: "That sounds like a whole lot of work" true, but you won't find a solution where this isn't true. But I don't see how this will cause you additional work over time. When a library changes, you will have to change your code, with or without this solution.

Comment: Just don't use plain old jars. Use Maven or don't use Maven, mixing the two approaches will always give you configuration hell